# Erro "Connection refused" ao conectar no PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

O erro acontece após digitar login e senha:

> "Deuorg.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that
>   the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting
>   TCP/IP connections."

estou fazendo a conexão dessa forma e necessito que fique assim por enquanto:

```
<%
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://postgres-postgresconection.jelastic/siscosi";
String usuario = "xxxx";
String senha = "xxxx";
try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, senha);
```

Comment: O servidor postgres está em uma maquina diferente da sua?

Comment: Como o erro já diz: Seu `hostname` e/ou `porta` está errada, veja se está digitado tudo corretamente ou se as informações são verídicas em relação ao endereço de seu servidor.

Comment: correção eu coloquei essa url primeiro :
 String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/nome do banco";
e o meu postgres está assim:
PostgreSQL 8.4.18 rodando em localhost:5432 -- Você está logado como usuário "webadmin".

agora não sei se o postgres do Jestastic

Comment: Entre no painel de controle do seu cloud e pegue as configurações do seu servidor e [edit]e a pergunta, daí fica mais fácil dizer qual será a string de conexão para ti

Comment: pessoal me informaram que o é erro no socket da conexão
o serviço do postgre deve estar desligado. Mas como ligo esse serviço?

Comment: Vá nos serviços do Windows e veja se está rodando. Abra o executar, digite services.msc e de enter. Procure postgresql e veja se está rodando.

Comment: @Roque, onde você está rodando seu servidor de aplicação Web?Também uso a plataforma Jelastic, seu problema deve o mesmo que já tive.

Answer (score 1):

Por padrão quando se cria um ambiente no **Jelastic** com um banco de dados, tal banco de dados só poderá ser acessado pelas aplicações no mesmo ambiente ou pela página Web (como o **phpPgAdmin**).

Então, para acessar o banco de dados é necessário habilitar a opção **Endereço IPv4 público**, e isso vai aumentar um pouco mais seu custo mensal. Fazendo assim, você receberá um **IP** para acessá-lo remotamente e então adicionar o IP como hostname na URL de conexão.

Resumindo, você tem de ter um IP válido para acessar remotamente seu banco de dados e sua URL de conexão ficará assim:

`"jdbc:postgresql://IPRecebido/siscosi"`

Mais informações você pode encontrar aqui: [Jelastic - Acesso remoto PostgreSQL](http://docs.jelastic.com/pt/remote-access-postgres)

Answer (score 0):

A url de conexão do Postgres deve seguir o seguinte modelo

```
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database
```

Se a porta não for especificada, ele utilizará a **padrão do postgres** que é **5432**

Aparentemente o nome informado para o host é inválido

> postgres-postgresconection.jelastic

Talvez falte o **.com** do endereço **postgres-postgresconection.jelastic.com** e a porta, se for diferente de 5432

Comment: coloquei assim agora e nada:
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://postgres-postgresconection.jelastic.com:5432/nome do banco"